# Inserting a navbar into wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Straigth to the point: I got the **twentytwelve** Theme from WordPress installed and changed its background + removed the default navbar. (commented it out)
Now how can I implement my bootstrap navbar that float on the top of the screen.
This is the navbar code:

```
<?php
if(!isset($nosession))
session_start();
}

/*if(isset($_COOKIE['username']))
{
  $_SESSION['username'] = $_COOKIE['username'];
  $_SESSION['loggedin'] = "true";
}*/

?>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="brand" href="#">IHES</a>
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="adopteren.php">Adopteren</a></li>
          <li><a href="webshop.php">WebWinkel</a></li>
          <li><a href="wallofsteen.php">Wall of Steen</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="icon-film" style="margin-top:-1px"></i> Videos <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="nieuws.php"><i class="icon-film"></i>Nieuws</a></li>
              <li><a href="interviews.php"><i class="icon-film"></i>Interviews</a></li>
              <li><a href="overig.php"><i class="icon-film"></i>Overig</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Steenoloog Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
        <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])){

          if(isset($_COOKIE['cart']))
          {
            echo '
              <li class="pull-right"><a href="shoppingcart.php"><i class="icon-shopping-cart icon-white"></i></a></li>
            ';
          }
          echo '<li class="navbar-form pull-right">
                  <a href="#">'.$_SESSION['username'].'</a>
                </li>';


          echo '<li class="navbar-form pull-right">
                  <a href="scripts/dologout.php" style="color: #FFF3F3;">Loguit</a>
                </li>';
        }else{
            echo '<div class="navbar-form pull-right">
                  <a href="login.php"><button type="submit" class="btn">Login Pagina</button></a>
                </div>';
        }
        ?>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That is my navbar code that I include on top of every .php page.

```
require "navbar.php";
```

But how can I use this with in the 2012 theme from wordpress?
I tried to just use the require and also link to the .css files from bootstrap.
But this only gives me the content of the navbar. It is missing the navbar itself.
(BTW: I pasted the code in the **header.php** file from the theme)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you include css?
 Also try include instead of require

Comment: I dont know how it happend but all is working now :P
Thanks for your time tho ;)

Comment: That's the "Ask StackOverflow Phenomenon". Your work detects that you went to the experts - it gives up and starts to behave.